# How to enable/disable textbox if the user already pick a file for upload using AsyncFileUpload?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP code:

`<ajax:AsyncFileUpload ID="fuFile" runat="server" Width="250px" />`

with a textbox  for description:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtFileDesc" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Wrap="true" style=" resize: none" Height="50px" MaxLength="200"></asp:TextBox>`

Now, I want  to enable the `txtFileDesc` textbox if the user "PICKED A FILE" (when the background of the file path turns green) like [this sample from http://www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx).

I already tried the solution from  other post's but none of them works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can handle **OnClientUploadStarted**  client side event to disable textbox and **OnClientUploadComplete** event to enable textbox after file has been uploaded completely.

Your fileupload should be like

```
<ajax:AsyncFileUpload ID="fuFile" runat="server" Width="250px" OnClientUploadStarted="OnClientUploadStartedFn" OnClientUploadComplete="OnClientUploadCompleteFn"  />
```

call this function on OnClientUploadStarted

```
 function OnClientUploadStartedFn () {
    $('#textboxId').attr('readonly','readonly');
   }
```

call this function on OnClientUploadComplete

```
function OnClientUploadCompleteFn() {
    $('#textboxId').removeAttr('readonly');
   }
```

Comment: can you post a code?.. I've already done that. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: I tried it sir, but it didn't work. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with .Net ver 3.5.

Comment: have you added any reference of jquery file. if not then please add

Comment: I manage to fix your code sir, Instead of the `ID` I use the HTML long ID which is `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFileDesc` then I made the attributes case sensitive. You don't need to have the JQuery.